# How to convert to text instead of general when exporting to csv

Tags: sql, excel, csv, powershell

I'm exporting a sql query to csv using windows powershell. Here is the code:

```
$previousdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).tostring("yyyyMMdd")
if ($previousdate.DayOfWeek -eq "Sunday") {$previousdate = $previousdate.AddDays(-2)}
$filename = "F:\User\test" + $previousdate + ".csv"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance dfasys2db-prd -InputFile "F:\User\Month End.sql" | ConvertTo-Csv -notype -Delimiter ","  | % {$_ -replace '"',''} | Select -Skip 1 | Out-File -FilePath $filename
```

When I do this it exports to csv, but the excel columns are using the General format and I need the text format, as the general format leaves characteristics in the data.

Is there a way for the columns to be text rather than general when I export?

Comment: _"... a way for the columns **to show as text** rather than general when you **import**"_ I think, is what you are trying to do.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

CSV files are pure text files, with no formatting at all contained within them. If you need the content to be formatted as text instead of general when you open it in Excel then I would recommend working with the Excel com object, configuring the formatting to your desired state, and then save the file as an Excel file (XLS/XLSX).